# In Ubuntu 18.04, how can I edit Google Chrome's launcher in the dash?

Tags: google-chrome, .desktop

Google Chrome tries to use Ubuntu's password keyring to store your passwords. Due to a faulty implementation though, this doesn't work in a useful way. The browser just spams you with dozens of keyring password prompts at every launch. Apparently, to make this go away, you could force Chrome to use its built in password storage, by adding this bit to the launcher command: `--password-store=basic`.

Now this works great for Chromium. All I had to do was use Main Menu (Alacarte) to edit its command and the password prompts disappeared from Chromium. I can't seem to make it work for Google Chrome, though. So far I edited Chrome's launchers in the following places:

- Chrome's entry in Main Menu (Alacarte)
- /usr/share/applications
- /local/share/applications

None of these seem to change the launcher in the dash, though. The launcher in the application picker was somehow fixed by one of those changes, I can start the browser from there and I get no popups. The dash seems to use a different launcher that is in a different place.

Comment: The browser can be a snap app. Have a look in this folder  `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` or simply use `locate *chrome*.desktop`

Comment: g-c can place a .desktop or a number of .desktops in ~/.local/share/applications. Why I've no clue, usually I delete them.. Do you have `Auto Sign-in` enabled?, if not try enabling it, Settings > Passwords & forms >  Manage passwords

Comment: @cmak.fr It's not a snap app.
Auto sign in is enabled, it has no effect on it.